# flutter combine two stream where the second depends on the first?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have two collection,

> 1. users collection
> 2. like collection.

in my like i have the list of like with there **id**, i am now using stream to fetch the list like user but. so if the user change his profile image it cant be updated in the like collection, so what i did is after fetching the list, i pass the id to another stream to get upadate from Users collection. this alot of bioler plate code. i am looking for way to combine this stream together.

here is a sample code

```
StreamBuilder(
stream: firestore
.collection('Matches')
.doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
.collection('Match')
.orderBy('chatTimeStamp').snapshots(),
 builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Container();
                        }
                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        }
                        if (snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty) {
                          return Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                RippleAnimation(
                                  repeat: true,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  minRadius: 100,
                                  ripplesCount: 6,
                                  child: Material(
                                    elevation: 8.0,
                                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      backgroundColor: themedata.darkTheme
                                          ? Colors.black
                                          : Colors.white,
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                        'assets/1.png',
                                      ),
                                      radius: 80.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Flexible(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'No Message Yet!',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: GoogleFonts.raleway(
                                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                        return ListView.separated(
                            separatorBuilder: (_, index) => Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 120.0, right: 40),
                                  child: Divider(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    thickness: 1.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              final data =
                                  snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['Match'];
                           
                              //here is where it depend on the value 
                              return StreamBuilder(
                                  stream: firestore
                                      .collection('users')
                                      .doc(data['id'])
                                      .snapshots(),
                                  builder: (context, snapshotid) {
                                    final active = snapshotid.data.data();
                                    if (snapshotid.hasError) {
                                      return Container();
                                    }
                                    if (snapshotid.connectionState ==
                                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                      return Center(
                                          child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                                    }
                                    if (snapshotid.connectionState ==
                                        ConnectionState.none) {
                                      return Container();
                                    }
                                    if (!snapshotid.hasData) {
                                      return Container();
                                    }
```

Comment: check `Stream.asyncExpand` method documentation

Answer (score 0):

For combining two streams you can use combine2 method from rxdart library. this library has all of the stream class features + some extra functionality which is really useful. for more detail you can see the official documentation [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/).

note: for using this library methods and functionalities you should also define streams by this library classes.
for example:
Stream stream, may be PublishSubject stream.

Comment: can you show mw examples on how this  Stream stream is declear in code

Comment: final firestore= PublishSubject(); then in your stream you can use this stream here. firestore.stream

Comment: this is the documentation about it with some examples/ https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html